# When input is 0 output is 1 and output is 0 when input is 1 in java

Tags: java, methods, binary, boolean, bitwise-operators

Write a method which will pass only one integer(1 or 0) as parameter. It will return 0 when input is 1 and return 1 when input is 0. The catch is **we cannot use any operator***.
I tried this approach. any other way available? Thanks in advance.

```
public BigInteger process(int i){
        BigInteger bi = BigInteger.valueOf(i);
        BigInteger one =BigInteger.valueOf(1);
        return bi.xor(one);
    }
```

Comment: `we cannot use any operator` thats mean your solution is also wrong for Assignment operator

Comment: A simple `if` or `if`-`else` statement?

Comment: No, we cant use if..else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could invert the value using an array sorted backwards.

```
public int invert(int i) {
    int[] ints = {1, 0};
    return ints[i];
}
```

EDIT: Here it is with a little error handling:

```
public int invert(int i) {
    try {
        int[] ints = {1, 0};
        return ints[i];
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        System.err.println("invert(int) was called with value " + i + ". Expected values are 0 and 1.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

As Ole pointed out in the comments the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` triggered when reading from a non-existing array cell is technically enough to prevent method misuse, but it does not hurt to deliver a little bit of additional debug information.

Comment: Wow, this is a smart answer!

Comment: You should add a bit validation, otherwise it will fail miserably, if I, a really evil caller pass -1 or 2

Comment: `=` is an Assignment operator

Comment: Nice logic man. btw Input can only contain 1 or 0. so can we use assert anyhow?

Comment: `assert`? Not without any operator. Also `assert` is not recommended for argument validation. I think under these constraints it’s fair just to let the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` propagate out of the method in case of a disallowed argument. The assignment operator can be done away with through inlining: `return new int[] {1, 0}[i];`. Some count `[]` (array lookup) as an operator too, though…